# Do the CTS tests run on rooted phones?

Tags: android, cts

I am trying to run the Android Compatibility tests on my rooted phone.  Are the tests supposed to work on rooted phones? For me, the tests ran on a non-rooted phone successfully, but not on rooted phone.  Did anyone notice the same thing?

Comment: tests works on rooted phone as well if you have rooted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Some tests will check the phone is rooted or not,

and those test will fail if your phone has been rooted.

For example, if your phone has been rooted

test *android.security.cts.BannedFilesTest # testNoSuInPath* will fail,

and the  error message would be:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: /system/xbin/su exists
```